# R Error in grid.Call with survminer :: ggsurvplot with new packages versions

Tags: r, ggplot2, version, survival, survminer

I use the ggsurvplot from survminer package in R to plot Kaplan-Meir curves. Here is the code and the following error:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)
library(survminer) 
km_fit_2cohorts <- survival::survfit(Surv(time_event_M, indic_Death) ~ cohort, data = data_2cohorts) 
survminer::ggsurvplot(km_fit_2cohorts, risk.table = TRUE, surv.scale = "percent")
```

> Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  :
> VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'NULL'
> In addition: Warning message:
> Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
> Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.

My R version : 4.0.2
packages versions: [1] stringr_1.4.0   survminer_0.4.8 ggpubr_0.4.0    survival_3.2-3  tidyr_1.1.2    ggplot2_3.3.2   dplyr_1.0.2     plyr_1.8.6      readr_1.3.1

In fact when testing the same code in another R:
R version : 4.0.2
packages versions: [1] survminer_0.4.8 ggpubr_0.4.0    survival_3.1-12 tidyr_1.1.0     ggplot2_3.3.2   dplyr_1.0.0     plyr_1.8.6      readr_1.3.1,
there is the same warning, but the plot is well printed. The R version is identical, as well as ggplot2 and survminer, but survival version is older.

So it seems that with the new versions of survival package, `ggsurvplot()` does not work anymore, which is very annoying. I cannot change easily the packages version on the platform where I work. Do you know a solution for future use of `ggsurvplot()` with last survival versions?

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: I was surprised to see a dataframe name beginning with "2". Are you sure this is a legal R name?

Comment: Thanks yes indeed it was a typo error when adapting the code to post it, I corrected it